# Outlook Client reading extended property value in custom column formula using view settings

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

We have our own archive system in which when a mail is archived or failed to archive we set a 'extended property' in the mail as a status flag '1' or '0'. So that we comes to know that mail is archived or not ,

We have extended property id and property name, Now what we are trying is to have seperate column to show the status of archive reading that extended property ,

[image]

Using above steps we have created the column feild.

Now in the below image there is option with fomula, I am just wondering if there a way to get that extended property to read and return the value set in that extended property with the help of formula or may be an other way.

[image]

If we get the value of Extended property here we can show the value in the custom column.

I have seen some question related to span dectection similar to this but here our case is bit different.

Or is there in EWS way to achieve this .